# Showing dynamic URL on previous and next page using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have API URL that is already paginated with 10 companies each.
Code to fetch

```
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const fetchJobs = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies/?page=${counter}`
        );
        const companies = await response.json();
        setCompanies(companies);
      };
      fetchJobs();
    } catch (error) {
      return <div style={{ margin: '20px' }}>No more companies to show</div>;
    }
  }, [counter]);
```

This is what I did to go to previous and next page

```
{companies.length === 0 ? (
            <div style={{ margin: '20px' }}>No more companies to show</div>
          ) : null}
          <ButtonGroup size='md' className='mb-2'>
            <Button
              variant='info'
              onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)}
              disabled={counter <= 1}
            >
              Previous
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant='info'
              onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}
              disabled={companies.length === 0}
            >
              Next
            </Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
        </div>
```

Route for this

```
  <Route exact path='/companies' component={CompanyListing} />
```

Problem is , I just managed to go to next and previous page with buttons but URL doesn't change . whichever page I visit, I am just at `/companies`, but I want to make something like this, If user goes to page 2, it has to show  `/companies/?page=2` . Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `history.push` from `react-router` to change the URL dynamically.

```
   history.push({
       pathname: '/companies',
       search: '?counter=2'
   });
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component from `react-router`. The `search` parameter of `to` prop can be used to change the queryParams in URL.

Then, your datatable component must be changed to utilise the query params from from URL to fetch And display the results.

Comment: Thank you. `history.push(`/companies/?page=${counter}`);` This line worked for me by using it after `setCompanies(companies);` .